# Meteor query is acting differently on server vs local environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Trying to debug a Meteor or Mongo error that only appears on meteor server deployments. Locally all is fine, and the query returns valid objects, but on servers it returns 'undefined'. Servers are meteor.com deployments and also on a mup/Digital Ocean server.

See the Repo for reproducing the error here: 
https://github.com/keyscores/meteorserverissue

```
Meteor.methods({
 append: function(){

  Aggregate.update({timeStamp: 1424311200000}, {$set: { credit: 111111}}); //this fails on server

  Aggregate.update({afterTaxTotal:2}, {$set: { credit: 222222}}); //this is successful on server

  Aggregate.update({title: "Bem-Vindo a Nova York"}, {$set: { credit: 333333}}); //this is successful on server

  console.log("Append Done");
 }
});
```

Seems to be an issue with timeStamp, or numbers, but can't see how/what causes it.

Lastly, I think Mongo and Node are at the same versions in all environments. What else could be the issue?

Comment: You should provide a minimal clonable reproduction has the issue may be somewhere else.

Comment: I think it may be related to how mongodb and the nodejs driver handle those big numbers and that there may be a discrepancy between versions. That's just a guess, but you should definitely check both your node, mongodb and meteor versions on local and remote. And perhaps a very minimal reproduction could go a long way.

Comment: thanks @mquandalle here is a repo for reproducing the error: https://github.com/keyscores/meteorserverissue

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail and the actual codebase it's hard to figure this out.

It's possible that you have auto publish enabled on dev but not on live?

Sounds like a publication or subscriptions issue to me.

In your example are you updating and inserting on different collections e.g.

```
CollectionOne.insert({title:title, timeStamp:timeStamp}); 

    CollectionTwo.update({title: title}, {$set: { value: 333}});
    //works fine on server and local

    CollectionThree.update({timeStamp: timeStamp}, {$set: { value: 333}});
    //fails on server, works fine locally

    CollectionFour.update({timeStamp: timeStamp, title: title}, {$set: { value: 333}});
    //fails on server, works fine locally

    CollectionFive.find({timeStamp: timeStamp})
    //returns [] on server but the data is in the collection
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The code is running in a  server-side method. I don't see how autopublish could affect it. I'm only interacting with one collection. There are other server-side operations that are doing fine in my codebase. Just this one annoying bug. Any other ideas?

Comment: Out of interest why are you updating the same collection with three different db queries?

You should get rid of the insert and update queries and use a single upsert query.

There could be something going on with latency. Swap your code out for a single upsert and redeploy.

Comment: Yes absolutely. This is just an example of how the different queries respond.

Comment: here is a repo in case you can reproduce. Thanks in advance!